# ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ARMHF (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 following these instructions:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

The site says that armhf is supportet. However when executing

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I always get the error

```
unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Same for desktop or basic install. Is there any idea what I could do?

`ros-latest.list` contains as first line `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main`, that should be ok...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241773/ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-mate-16.04-armhf-(raspberry-pi-3)/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-16**:
I am alos using the Raspberry Pi 3 under Ubuntu Mate. It will be good to be in touch with you and have some discussion in this regard. I am also facing various kinds of problems, for example in the installation for rosaria. It will be good to be in touch with you for this purpose kam@hanyang.ac.kr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the [shadow-fixed repos](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository).

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2016-08-16**:
Great, that works with the desktop version! Can you poste it as answer, then I mark as complete?

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2016-08-22**:
I also updated the instructions that I linked above...